# Add limits to the integration symbol in matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel()

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, python-3.6, tex

I want the ylabel to be of the form in the below figure.
[image]

I have used the below line to get the integral symbol on the ylabel without the limits.

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\int du/(1+u^{2})$')
```

I need to know how to bring in the limits 0 and x in the integral symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilites. First, you could use the generic `_` and `^` for lower and upper limits:

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\int_0^y du/(1+u^{2})$')
```

Personally however, I occasionally don't like the formatting (in my setup). You could enable Latex in matplotlib and then label the axes with that, if that's the same for you. As an example (just for simplicity, its of course not a correct labeling..)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

plt.plot(b,b)
plt.ylabel(r'$\int\limits_0^x  du/{(1+u^2)}$')
plt.show()
```

You can play around a little, if you know any Latex and want to change the formatting and try some stuff, such as:

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\int\limits_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}^{\scriptstyle x}  \frac{du}{1+u^2}$', size=12)
```

Although honestly, the latex support is kinda bad.